# unable to get post data using VBA

Tags: vba, msxml

I am trying to post data & get response text programatically but nothing seems to be posted & return values, i am getting same HTML tag which is there in default webpage. my code is:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim htm As Object
Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "POST", "http://dreamsware.info/bahrio/loc/index.php", False
   .send "mcc=404&mnc=10&lac=246&cid=20001"
    htm.body.innerHTML = .responsetext
End With
Debug.Print htm.body.innerHTML
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of your code here  (in a messagebox).

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
<html>
<head>
<title>GSM LAC/CID -> location test</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,
          SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
        font-size:12;
    }
    td {
        font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, Arial,
          SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
        font-size:12;
    }
</style>
<center>
<table width="450">
<tr><td>
</td></tr>
</table>
<font size="1"><a href="http://bahrio.blogspot.com" target="_top">Bahri Okuroglu</a></font>
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes">MCC - Mobile Country Code</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="5" name="mcc" value="286"><br />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code">MNC - Mobile Network Code</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="5" name="mnc" value="01"><br />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td>LAC - Location Area Code</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="5" name="lac" value="21534"><br />
            </td>

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

But you make a mistake of not testing what happens.

The URL has to be 100% correct. Unlike a browser there is no code to fix urls.

The purpose of my program is to get error details.

How I get a correct URL is to type my url in a browser, navigate, and the correct URL is often in the address bar. The other way is to use Properties of a link etc to get the URL.

Also Microsoft.XMLHTTP maps to Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP maps to Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0. Try a later one

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a

Comment: Hi thanks for response, its my mistake did nit explained actual problem, when i am sending data it is not getting posted & i am not getting desired response data.

Comment: Well if you adapt my code you'll get the reason why. You must test for errors.

Comment: As I proved yourcode works here, so it's a configuration problem. Test for errors. Every program you write should test for errors. Then it will tell you why.

Comment: Try using `Get` instead of `Post`.

Comment: Don't worry about the last comment, I've already proved `Post` works.

Comment: hmnn.. getting error 424 on line BS.Write File.ResponseBody.. i hv given ref to MS DAO 3.51 lib.

Comment: This is the adodb com server. C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll.

Comment: Error 424(0x1A8) Object required at  file.getAllResponseHeaders

Comment: Then the object creation is probably failing. I concatinate the string before printing it. BTW you have torun the script with CSCript as it prints to a console. Change tis tis `Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &` to `wscript.echo`. Then it will print as much as it can.